# How can I use IndexOf with Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, indexof

I'm a beginner in Java, so I apologize if this seems too easy for you to reply, still I hope I can get a little help from here.

I wanted to get an input from the user with `Scanner`, writing a sentence. 
Then the user would pick a word from that sentence. 
And then with `string.indexof("")`, the program should count from which number the  word starts in that sentence. 
But the result is always -1. And I don't understand why.

```
String a,b;

Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please write a sentence");
y=sc.next();

Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please pick a word from that sentence");

System.out.println("The word starts from=" + (y.indexOf(a=sc2.next())));
```

Comment: Try printing the values of "y" and "a=sc2.next()" in the console after the user have typed them, and then give us the output

Answer (score 1):

> But the result is always -1. And I don't understand why.

The only scenario in which `-1` will be returned is if there is no such occurrence of the specified `String`.

[`Scanner#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) only returns what comes before a space, meaning anything after space is ignored. It seems that you'll need to use the [`Scanner#nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) to store the whole sentence rather than [`Scanner#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()).

e.g.

```
y = sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    String a,b;

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please write a sentence");
    String y=sc.nextLine();

    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please pick a word from that sentence");

    System.out.println("The word starts from=" + (y.indexOf(a=sc2.nextLine())));
}
```

Comment: Please do not simply put the solution code. Add some details with your answer as well.